# How to hide select option with condition Less than (<)

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two select lists call `#ageSelect1` and `#ageSelect2`. I want to hide `#ageSelect2` options when page load less than some value. Following code is not working. But

`$("#ageSelect2 option[value =" + ageSelectStart + "]").hide();`

code is working. how to use less than condition.?

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var ageSelectStart = 21;
    var ageSelectEnd = 35;
    $("#ageSelect2 option[value <" + ageSelectStart + "]").hide();
  });
< /script>
```

Comment: do you want to hide the #ageSelect2 or its one option???

Comment: i want to hide `#ageSelect2` all options (1 to 80),  less than `ageSelectStart`. Finally 1 to 20 are should be hided.

Comment: there were some answers pointed you that you need to exclude the operator from quote...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var ageSelectStart = 21;
  var ageSelectEnd = 35;
  var elSelect1 = $("#ageSelect1"),
      elSelect2 = $("#ageSelect2");
  
 elSelect1.find('option').each(function(index, el){
   if($(el).val() < ageSelectStart){
     //$(el).prop('disabled', true).hide();
     $(el).remove();
     }
 });

 elSelect2.find('option').each(function(index, el){
   if($(el).val() > ageSelectEnd){
     //$(el).prop('disabled', true).hide();
     $(el).remove();
     }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="startage" id="ageSelect1">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
</select>
<select name="endage" id="ageSelect2">
  <option value="36">36</option>
  <option value="37">37</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try this

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var ageSelectStart = 21;
     var ageSelectEnd = 35;

     var selectedElement =document.getElementById("ageSelect2")
     for (var i=0; i<selectedElement.length; i++)
     {
        if (selectedElement.options[i].value < ageSelectStart)
        {
           selectedElement.options[i].hide();
        }
     }
  });
< /script>
```

Comment: It doesn't hide options less than 21

Comment: @GeethWelagedara I have edit my answer please check whether it's ok y down vote??

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var ageSelectStart = 21;
    var ageSelectEnd = 35;

    $("#ageSelect2").find("option").show().each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("value") < ageSelectStart) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  }); 
</script>
```